# Assigning caps lock key for contextual menu (right click) on OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping, capslock

I'd like to remap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to right click - for the cases where I can focus on objects with cursor keys, or tab.

For instance after selecting files in Finder I'd like to push <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and get the contextual menu you'd get on right click.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/extra.html) keyboard driver to assign a regular key code to caps lock (e.g. enter, something you probably don't use -- it's *not* the same as return).

A more complete reference of known key codes than the one in the screen shot on the site is [here](http://www.codemacs.com/coding/applescript/applescript-key-codes-reference.8288271.htm) — although they're for AppleScript, they should be the same, with `Escape` having the `code 53` in both cases.

---

Use [QuicKeys](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/) to create a script that is invoked when you press your hotkey.

Click `+` to create a shortcut. *Add Step » User Actions » Clicks » Click*. Configure to right-click without holding, both *Click Location* and *Release Location* being 0/0 relative to the *Mouse*.

Comment: _Click Location and Release Location being 0/0 relative to the Mouse._


So then, focus will be wherever your mouse pointer is, not where you focus with the keyboard, so you need to touch the mouse anyway?